# How to get an array element value repeated based on another array element

Tags: php, arrays, element, key-value

I am trying to get a value repeated number of times the value of an array element
I have the following arrays

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array(3, 2, 5);
foreach ($b as $x) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
        echo print_r($i).'<br>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11
21
31
11
21
11
21
31
41
51
```

I expect the output to be:-

```
1112233333
```

Comment: Is `$a` supposed to be doing anything in this code?

Comment: You shouldn't echo the return from print_r in this code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you go -

```
<?php
    $a = array(1,2,3);
    $b = array(3,2,5);
    $index = 0;
    foreach($b as $x) {
        for($j = 1;$j <= $x; ++$j) {
            echo $a[$index];
        }
        ++$index;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array(3, 2, 5);
foreach($a as $i => $x){
    echo str_repeat($x, $b[$i]) .'<br>';
}
```